# What does the :: indicate in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am implementing an API in Rails 3, and noticed an example controller defined like `class Api::ToursController < ApplicationController`. Does anyone know what the to colons indicate? Is it inheritance? Or is it indicating extending the ToursController? I have tried searching for an answer, but have not come up with anything.

Here is what I am referencing: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Set-up-rabl-for-Ruby-on-Rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator (i.e. namespace operator) in many languages, including C++ and Ruby, so it's not specific to Rails.

In Ruby, modules define namespaces, so you can see code like this:

```
Net::HTTP.get 'stackoverflow.com'
```

Which calls the `get` class method on the `HTTP` class in the `Net` module.

In Rails, namespaces allow you to better organize your code (e.g. to separate your API controllers from the rest), and are implemented as modules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So does this mean the `ToursController`, is entirely different from a class defined as `class ToursController < ApplicationController`? Do you know how to make the rails generator define a controller in a namespace?

Comment: Yes, you can have completely different controllers with the same name under different namespaces. To generate a controller in a namespace, you can do this: `rails g controller api::tours` or this: `rails g controller api/tours`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am new to rails and this saved me a lot of headache. I was able to get this working, and am glad to have my api logic away from my browser presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

`Api::ToursController` indicates that there is an outer Module called `Api` , in which the `ToursController` class is located.  `::` is the namespace operator.

Sometimes you see a module name preceded with :: , e.g. `::Something` , this indicates to Ruby to look in the outer-most namespace (Main) for the Class or Module called Something. This typically happens when you're somewhere in the source code of a gem and it references an outer Class or Module.

You can do `include Api` to include everything in the Module Api at the current level, this way you don't need the namespace operator, and can use `ToursController` without prefixing it with 'Api::'

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the clarification. If you use `include Api` does it work like this:`include Api
     class ToursController < ApplicationController`

Comment: yes, but in case of sub-classing, it's probably a better idea to explicitly use the fully-qualified name (unless you're inside your own library code internals)

Answer (score 0):

It's namespace! Module::Class.method